# Does Marklogic database support Lemmatization?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-10

I see Marklogic database support for stemming but does it support Lemmatization. If yes then how do we implement this feature.

Answer (score 0):

The [Bitext stemmer](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/languages#id_58237) supports options that you can specify in the `args` parameter of [`clang:stemmer`](https://docs.marklogic.com/clang:stemmer) or [`clang.stemmer`](https://docs.marklogic.com/clang.stemmer).

> `algorithm=value`
> Which stemming algorithm to use. If not specified, MarkLogic uses the default algorithm for the language.
>
> Choose from the following values: arabic, danish, dutch, english, finnish, french, german, german2, hungarian, italian, porter (Porter algorithm for English), portuguese, romanian, russian, spanish, swedish, turkish, tamil, persian, korean, english2, french2, german3, italian2, spanish2, swedish2. **The values english2, french2, german3, italian2, spanish2, and swedish2 specify a lemmatizing algorithm for that language, for use with Bitext dictionaries.**